# How to Simplify Asynchronous Programming in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I come from a C# background having used async/ await.  I am trying to find a "less verbose" way of programming using a library.
( specifically the Microsoft Playwright library for browser automation )

```
let (~~) = Async.AwaitTask
let getLastPageNumber(page: IPage) = 
    let playwright = ~~Playwright.CreateAsync() |> Async.RunSynchronously
    let browser = ~~playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions(Headless = false )) |> Async.RunSynchronously
    ~~page.GotoAsync("https://go.xero.com/BankRec/BankRec.aspx?accountID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&page1") |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
    let lastPageLink = ~~page.QuerySelectorAsync("#mainPagerEnd") |> Async.RunSynchronously
    if lastPageLink = null then
        //this is the last page
        1
    else
        let lastPageNumber = ~~lastPageLink.GetAttributeAsync("href") |> Async.RunSynchronously
        lastPageNumber |> int
```

I have shortened things a bit using the alias ~~ for Async.AwaitTask but it seems to be a lot of code to do something that was a lot easier in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Async.RunSynchronously` should only be used as a very last resort because it blocks a thread to perform the computation, which defeats the purpose of using async/tasks.

The F# equivalent of C#'s async/await is to use F#'s `Async` type, and the `async` computation expression. However, if you're using a .NET library which uses the .NET `Task` type then you can use the [TaskBuilder.fs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskBuilder.fs) library which has a `task` computation expression.

Then you would write the function like this:

```
open FSharp.Control.Tasks

let getLastPageNumber(page: IPage) =  task {
    let! playwright = Playwright.CreateAsync()
    let! browser = playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions(Headless = false ))
    let! _ = page.GotoAsync("https://go.xero.com/BankRec/BankRec.aspx?accountID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&page1")
    let! lastPageLink = page.QuerySelectorAsync("#mainPagerEnd")
    if lastPageLink = null then
        //this is the last page
        return 1
    else
        let! lastPageNumber = lastPageLink.GetAttributeAsync("href")
        return lastPageNumber |> int
}
```

Inside the computation expression (also called a builder) `let!` is used to await tasks.

Note that this function now returns `Task<int>` rather than `int`, so the caller would probably need to follow a similar pattern and propogate the task further.

You can read more about using `async` in F# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async). Some of that knowledge can also be applied to the `task` computation expression.

Comment: - Thanks,  that code is MUCH nicer - and thanks for the understanding.    does it always need to be a Task or are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: @MartinThompson You can convert any tasks to asyncs as well and use the `async` builder, but if you then need to change it back to a task at some point anyway then it's better to stick with tasks all the way through. It all depends on what happens with the output of this function.